# How to use geoNear for List of Articles, when Addresses are in separate table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb-query

I need a RoR mongoDB query to list articles within a given radius, sorted by `created_at`.

The challenge is that addresses are saved in separate table and referenced by key/id out of articles. Don't know how to make query with geoNear for this scenario.

Also pagination needed and performant query desirable.

Currently approaching like:

1. Get addresses within defined radius
2. Get articles associated to address results out of 1.
3. sort_by address (geoNear default)

Pagination is making usage of `last_address_id`. Also here have an issue, as last page is in loop.

```
    #seaches_controller.rb
    def index
        @addresses = 
        Address.get_addresses_with_radius(article_search_params).to_a
        @address_hash = @addresses.group_by{|a| a['_id'].to_s}
        @articles = Article.includes(:gift, :category)
                           .where(  transaction_status: 
                              {
                                '$nin' => ["concluded"]
                              },
                              address_id: 
                              { 
                                :$in => @addresses.map{|a| a['_id'].to_s} 
                              }
                            ).to_a
                        .sort_by{|m| 
                              @addresses.map{|a| 
    a['_id']}.index(m['address_id']) }
end



#address.rb
 def self.get_addresses_with_radius(params, additional_query={})
    #raw query for aggreegate with geoNear
      last_maximum_distance = params[:last_maximum_distance] || 0 # in 
meeters
      radius = params[:radius] || 5000000 #In Meters 

      query_params = additional_query

      if params[:last_address_id] 
          query_params[:_id] ||= {}
          query_params[:_id] = query_params[:_id].merge({ '$ne' =>  
         (BSON::ObjectId(params[:last_address_id])) } )
      end

      addresses_in_radius = 
        Address.collection.aggregate([
          {
            '$geoNear': 
            {
              near: 
              { 
                type: "Point", 
                coordinates: [ params[:lat].to_f, params[:lon].to_f ]  
              },
              distanceField: "distance_from",  #GeoNear Will atomatically distance as distance_from_field
              minDistance: last_maximum_distance.to_f,
              maxDistance: radius,
              query: query_params,
              #query:{ 'location.0': {'$ne' =>  
params[:last_lat].to_f},'location.1': {'$ne' => params[:last_lon].to_f}},
              spherical: true
            }
          },
            {"$limit": params[:per_page].to_i}

          ])
      addresses_in_radius
  end
```

Currently I'm getting the list of articles sorted by addresses/distance, as per default geoNear behavior => should be by `created_at`.

Pagination is somehow based on addresses => should ideally be based on articles.

Pagination is buggy, as last page is loading in loop => loop-bug to go away.

Not sure if best is to first search for articles and then addresses, or first addresses and then get the articles; relevant note: all within defined radius.

Comment: anybody out there who can help on that? many thanks in advance!